# How to get ERC-20 transfer events using curl?

Tags: erc-20, json-rpc

I want to check whether my full node has historical logs correctly stored.

How can I query historical ERC-20 transfer events, or any historical Solidity events, using UNIX `curl` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query ERC-20 logs by their `topic` field `0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef`.

Here is an example JSON-RPC query to get `Transfer` events between blocks 10,100,100 - 10,100,999 on any EVM compatible  blockchain:

```shell
curl \
    "https://mynode.example.com"  \
    --location \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --request POST \
    --data-raw '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"]}],"fromBlock": 10100100,"toBlock":10100999,"id":1}'
```

The correct result looks like:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":[{"address":"0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56","topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000f83bf708c3e3bd57f24411f6fc67f5","0x000000000000000000000000d14e0b9eba0010e97f57cbd9042215499b53bc47"],"data":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000048f769c2b768980000","blockNumber":"0x188cad2","transactionHash":"0x1df61528ae4a3c4cc0435e732597b75bf15e5aafdea1d9abfd0588f62fde1e08","transactionIndex":"0x0","blockHash":"0xf398c8b6f2ea74dc0e8fcd83acce91abd128d1ca9dc94ff4e0aabedae3079ee4","logIndex":"0x0","removed":false},{"address":"0x4136129ac3ac90cf9817548b24d35e73e9457e05","topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x000000000000000000000000d14e0b9eba0010e97f57cbd9042215499b53bc47","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000f83bf708c3e3bd57f24411f6fc67f5"],"data":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000608a52c2254c572c6","blockNumber":"0x188cad2","transactionHash":"0x1df61528ae4a3c4cc0435e732597b75bf15e5aafdea1d9abfd0588f62fde1e08","transactionIndex":"0x0","blockHash":"0xf398c8b6f2ea74dc0e8fcd83acce91abd128d1ca9dc94ff4e0aabedae3079ee4","logIndex":"0x1","removed":false},...
```